Automorphisms and existence of isotrivial non-trivial families of complex manifolds
I never attended a course in deformation theory, so I'm trying to catch the meaning of a statement I encountered during a seminar.
Let's begin by fixing some notations: let $f:X \rightarrow S$ be a smooth, proper, holomorphic family of complex manifolds and let $X_0$ be the special fiber over $0 \in S$. I know there are some classic results concerning the existence of a universal deformation family of a fixed manifold $X_0$ (for example, the vanishing of $H^0(X_0, T_{X_0})$ guarantees it); I usually denote this family by
$$\mathcal{X} \rightarrow \operatorname{Def}(X_0).$$
Now, I've been told that there may be problems if $X_0$ admits non-trivial automorphisms, because then there may exist non-trivial families, whose fibers are all isomorphic to each others (isotriviality?). Because of this eventuality, you also need to specify the isomorphism between $X_0$ (the given manifold) and the special fiber of $f:X \rightarrow S$.

How does the existence of a non-trivial isotrivial family break the existence of a universal family if you don't specify the isomorphism to the special fiber?
Is there any reasonable explicit example of this phenomenon so that I can convince myself that it's a real problem?


Did you try to work out the case of elliptic curves?

All fibers in a universal family are pairwise non-isomorphic, so you can get from it an isotrivial family by pullback only if the base change is constant, but then the pullback family is trivial.
A typical example of an isotrivial family is the following. Assume $G \subset \mathrm{Aut}(X_0)$ be a finite subgroup. Let $U$ is a scheme with a free action of $G$. Consider the family
$$
f \colon (X_0 \times U)/G \to U/G.
$$
After base change along $U \to U/G$ it becomes trivial with fiber $X_0$, hence it is isotrivial with fiber $X_0$.
Now assume that $U$ is connected and $G \not\subset \mathrm{Aut}^0(X_0)$. Then $f$ is not trivial. Indeed, if its, then pulling back to $U$ its trivialization, we obtain a second trivialization of the map $X_0 \times U \to U$ with the property that the morphism
$$
\phi \colon U \to \mathrm{Aut}(X_0)
$$
given by the "difference" of the two trivializations satisfies
$$
\phi(gu) = g \circ \phi(u).
$$
Therefore, the map $\phi(u) \circ \phi(u_0)^{-1} \colon U \to \mathrm{Aut}(X_0)$ contains $G$ in the image, a contradiction.

Thank you for your answer! What do you mean by $\operatorname{Aut}^0(X_0)$?

This is the standard notation for the connected component of the unit in the group of automorphisms.
